# How to show/hide a 3 levels menu nav in css?

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="current"> level 1 </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="children">level 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a> level 3 </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I create a simple show/hide using css display none/block?

Currently doing this but only gets me to the second level and I'm a bit logically stucked:

```
ul ul,
ul ul ul {
   display: none;
}

.current .children {
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple, and there are dozens of examples everywhere. A little search might help.

```js
ul ul {
    display: none;
}

ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

ul > li > ul > li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please theck your code to be valid, I see horrible things like "<a/>". Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Merec/UHEQn/

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use jQuery you could check out http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$('#yourlinkID').click(function() {
     $('#yourbodyID').toggle()
});
```

The above code toggles the visibility of the element with #yourbodyID when the element with #yourlinkID is clicked.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Not everything must be done with javascript... and js/jquery is not tagged.

Comment: Apologies. I was just trying to provide an opinion. First attempt at answering a question, sorry I didn't meet your standards :(.

Comment: no that's fine, thanks. At least you didn't try to close a simple question with supported code or provide a rude answer wich pointed me to the fact that "there are dozens of examples everywhere". I'll accept yours even tho I won't use it as I knew of a jQuery solution. Just a matter of calm and respect. Thank you.

Comment: @djjavo actually I can't accept it just for democracy with other users needing this. But I'm sure you'll understand. Thanks a lot.